# Is there a way to truncate text using liquid markups

Tags: liquid, catalog

I am looking to use liquid markups to truncate text of a product name. I know you can truncate through character count or word count, but I am looking to truncate a product name, almost like text to columns.

For example, if a product name is "Electric Guitar - Sky Blue", I want to truncate the product name only, so it just says "Electric Guitar". Every product name contains the " - ", so this would be consistent across the product set.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can split product title with `-` and first name is print

Example:  `{{ product.title | split:'-' | first }}` 
it will split from `-` and print `Electric Guitar`.